# python- string equality and ord() comparison?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, equality

```
 s1 = request.args.get('s1', '') 
 s2 = request.args.get('s2', '') 

    if '' not in [s1, s2]:
        if s1 == s2:
          if all(ord(c1) is ord(c2) for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2)):
            msg = "first"
          else:
            msg += "second"
        else:
          msg = "thrid"
      else:
        msg = 'fourth'
```

I want this piece of code to print "second".

I tried these inputs
s1 = ".0" and s2 = "0.00"

Could anyone please explain in brief what "`if all(ord(c1) is ord(c2) for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2)):`" means exactly?

I understand that it relates to string equality as well as comparing the ord() on strings and wanted to know how these are different.

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS : Please excuse the indentation. Python beginner here!

Comment: Please don't delete your [negatively-received question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198062/python-strings-equality-and-ord-comparison#40198062) just to wipe the downvotes and criticism.

Comment: You are having 3k+ reputation, but still you do not have proper indentation in the code. You should be knowing how to ask the question by now.

Comment: @anonymous: I haven't programmed in python so please excuse the indentation. For that matter ive even mentioned that in my question.

Comment: @Aditya: It is independent of the language. When you paste the code here, shouldn't it be formatted. And in Python, scope is defined based on the indentation. Incorrect indentation means your code is good for nothing

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 : I'm new to python and was asking for help. I did even mention that in the question and comments. Wanted to rephrase it and make myself as clear as possible so added a new question

Comment: @anonymous: I've clearly asked a conceptual question, plus i dont even know how to indent in python. I was expecting help instead of criticism. sigh.

Comment: The only difference between this question and the one you deleted is the last line about excusing the indentation. If you post a question that doesn't meet the site's standards, you should fully expect criticism, which is intended to encourage you to _improve the question_ rather than cheat the reputation system.

Comment: @Aditya: I am not criticizing. But as the matter of fact, Python is all about indentation. Anyway added the explanation behind your question that you might find useful.

Comment: @anonymous: Thanks for the help..

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Thanks for your pointers, as soon as I could edit the question, i felt the question was taking a step behind focusing more on matters which were defeating the purpose of my asking the question in the first place. Please excuse my ineptness at python since i'm only a beginner.

Comment: If you realize that your question has become pointless for any reason, deleting it is indeed the proper course of action, but why repost the exact same content? This has nothing to do with your ability with Python and everything to do with the fact that your question was unclear and too broad, and you deleted it and reposted it in an apparent attempt to avoid losing rep. Please do not do this.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I'm sorry if you believe that i deleted the question to avoid losing rep, but thats not the case! I have noted that downvoted questions receive lesser replies than normal ones, so wanted to receive make myself clearer and receive help. But I do understand your valid concern. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to note here that users above 10k rep can view deleted questions, and are thus able to compare your deleted question to this one and see the extent of your improvements (viz, none). Please don't try to fool the community into answering your inappropriate questions.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I do acknowledge that the question was unclear, based on the comments I did try to make it better. Isn't it better to have unclear questions to be deleted and any suggestions to be based off of constructive feedback/criticism. Let me know how i can improve the question. Hope you are having a great day. Thanks!

Comment: You reposted the exact same question with no changes, though. Why do you keep trying to convince me of something that I can clearly see isn't true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no 100% sure way of making that piece of code print second, since interning is an implementation detail.

CPython interns integers in the `[-5, 256]` range,

So you'll need a character that when it's passed to `ord` returns something > 256.

```
>>> s1 = "asdሴ"
>>> s2 = "asdሴ"
>>> s1 == s2
True
>>> all(ord(c1) is ord(c2) for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))
False
```

`all(ord(c1) is ord(c2) for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))` checks if every `ord(c1)` has the same `id` as `ord(c2)`.

From the `id` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
>
> > CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

Comment: The question asks what that snippet means, not how to make it print a certain result.

Answer (score -1):

In plain english, `if all(ord(c1) is ord(c2) for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))` means that ALL the values of `ord(s1[i])` and `ord(s2[i])` for `i` ranging from `0` to `len(s1 or s2)` (where `c1` and `c2` if the reference for `ord(s1[i])` and `ord(s2[i])`) is same for both the lists

Check [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) document. As per the document:

> **zip()** returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th
>   element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The returned
>   list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument
>   sequence

For example:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2 ,3]
>>> l2 = [7, 8, 9]
>>> zip(l1, l2)
[(1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9)]
```

Now `[ord(c1) is ord(c2) for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2)]` will return the tuple list of `True/False` value based on the condition `ord(c1) is ord(c2)` where `c1` and `c2` are `tuple` pair from the previous list of tuple returned by `zip()`.

Now the last part. if `all()` will return `True` if the list `[ ... ]` of `True/False` value mentioned above will be having all the values as `True`. In case any single item is as `False`, `all()` will return the value as `False`